# Express matrix whose components are coefficients of convex combination that generates $m^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, induction, combinations

> **Problem:** Given an integer $m$. We have \begin{align*}  m &=m\\  m^2 & = m(m-1) + k\\  m^3 & = m(m-1)(m-2) + 3m(m-1) + k \end{align*}
> Now the matrix whose components (in column) are coefficients of convex
> combination that generates $m$, $m^2$ and $m^3$ is $$A_3 =
>  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$
> Find the matrix $A_n$ and obserse what happens if $n$ goes to infinity
> (find infinity matrix?).

**My attempt:** For the question finding $A_n$, I have completed by induction and here is my solution
\begin{align*}
a_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } i>j\\
1 & \text{ if } i = j\\
i\cdot a_{i,j-1} + a_{i-1,j-1} & \text{ if } i<j
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

For the moment, I have stucked here. I hope that you could give me some idea to deal with this problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: @MikeEarnest I have read the link you gave. However, I have not seen what happens if $n$ goes to $_\infty$.